# on duplicate entry add name if empty php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

Clarification of what I'm trying to accomplish:
**Update "user name", if there is a record with the same e-mail but no name. if user already has a name, then don't make any changes**

I have a website where all users can be "subscribers, entrepreneurs or investors". If a subscriber (of whom I have previously only asked for email) chooses to upload a business idea then that person will probably use the same e-mail address as before only this time adding a name. So I'd like to INSERT INTO, and if e-mail already exists - add the name, but only if there is not a name there already (so that a person cannot simply over write somebody else's details).

I've gotten this far:

```
 mysql_query("
     INSERT INTO users
         (email, name)
     VALUES
         ('" .$epost. "',  '" .$namn. "')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name=VALUES(name)   -->[if name == '', else do nothing...]
 ");
```

Now it replaces the current name with a new one if different.

I searched "on duplicate update if field empty"
and found:
http://forums.aspfree.com/sql-development-6/on-duplicate-key-update-but-only-if-value-isn-t-482012.html (merging?)

[conditional on duplicate key update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044874/conditional-on-duplicate-key-update) (closer, but I don't want to update it if it differs, only if the field is empty.)

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/914328-duplicate-key-update-only-null-values (if the input is blank.. well it's not)

http://boardreader.com/thread/Insert_on_duplicate_key_update_only_if_c_can8Xachr.html (the layout of this page got me lost)

http://www.digimantra.com/tutorials/insert-update-single-mysql-query-duplicate-key/ (it simply updates)

I believe **this might be** kind of **what I'm after** (?) http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/1/18/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql but I haven't managed to make it work

This code:

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='".$namn."'
WHERE email='".$epost."' AND name =''");
```

updates the name, only if it's previously null, and that's what I'm after *however* it does not insert a new record if email doesn't already exist.

My table
[image: the table]

So I tried this:

```
  mysql_query("
     INSERT INTO users
     SELECT email, 'victoria' FROM users 
     WHERE email='victoria@hejsan.se' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'victoria'
 ");
```

and I tried this:

```
   mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO users
    SELECT email, 'yay' from users
    WHERE email='victoria@hejsan.se'
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
    UPDATE name = values(name)
 ");
```

from @Fluffeh 's answer

but nothing happens. Did i misinterpret the answer?

It just hit me that if someone already has an account then they should also have a password already, and so I'll just ask them to verify their password, and make sure I do an AJAX call while they insert their e-mail to see if the e-mail is already registered :)  And so then this is no longer an issue, and I think that is the solution I'll go with. !)

Comment: And what's the problem now? What exactly did not work?

Comment: What went wrong with the last approach? Show your code for that one

Comment: The problem he has now is that the `insert... on duplicate...` syntax will destroy the records he has, which as his question states is not what he wants to do.

Comment: Your code that is seen here is open to SQL injection. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or the better approach, prepared statements with the PDO extension. Also, on a side note: this was a lucky example, but using local language in code is a very bad idea as nobody will understand the variable names or worse, you will have to translate them and break the script while at it.

Comment: I am using $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["dinEpostadress"]);   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that you could use the `insert .... on duplicate key...` syntax to solve your issue would be if `name` and `email` made a composite key - and I think you would be better off using an auto_increment as a primary key.

You might have to put a little logic into the PHP to do a check first, then insert or update - or write a function to do that same test for you - but neither will be a simply query that you can just fire off.

Edit: Not sure if this is what you want to do, but I think that the best solution for your requirements is to actually use two tables in a one to many relationship.

```
Table-Users
id | email | name

create table users(
    id int(10) not null auto_increment,
    email varchar(100),
    name varchar(100),
    primary key(email, name)
    );

Table-Ideas
id | userID | idea

create table users(
    id int(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
    userID int(10) not null,
    idea text
    );
```

With the primary key on the table, you can safetly do an `insert... duplicate...` without worrying about over-writing folks. The second table will however allow you to have the ideas stored safetly locked to the user, and let you have a number of ideas per user. As the relationship is the `users.id` to `ideas.userID` you won't lose who owns it even if their details are updated.

Edit: (aka, ZOMG *facepalm*)

```
$query="
    update users 
        set name='".$userName."' 
    where 
        email='".$userEmail."' 
        and name is null";
```

Edit 2: (aka, *wipes brow*)

```
insert into users 
    select email, '".$namn."' from users where email='".$epost."' 
    on duplicate key 
        update name = values (name);
```

and here it is working:

```
mysql> create table test1 (myName varchar(10) unique, myEmail varchar(10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 values ('Tom','something');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 values('Nick',null);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from test1;
+--------+-----------+
| myName | myEmail   |
+--------+-----------+
| Tom    | something |
| Nick   | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 select myName, myEmail from test1 
where myName='Tom' on duplicate key update myEmail = values (myEmail);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test1;
+--------+-----------+
| myName | myEmail   |
+--------+-----------+
| Tom    | something |
| Nick   | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 select 'Tom', myEmail from test1 
where myName='Tom' on duplicate key update myEmail = values (myEmail);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test1;
+--------+-----------+
| myName | myEmail   |
+--------+-----------+
| Tom    | something |
| Nick   | NULL      |
+--------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 select myName, 'Something Else' from test1 
where myName='Tom' on duplicate key update myEmail = values (myEmail);
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 1

mysql> select * from test1;
+--------+------------+
| myName | myEmail    |
+--------+------------+
| Tom    | Something  |
| Nick   | NULL       |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 select myName, null from test1 
where myName='Nick' on duplicate key update myEmail = values (myEmail);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test1;
+--------+------------+
| myName | myEmail    |
+--------+------------+
| Tom    | Something  |
| Nick   | NULL       |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test1 select myName, 'yay' from test1 
where myName='Nick' on duplicate key update myEmail = values (myEmail);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test1;
+--------+------------+
| myName | myEmail    |
+--------+------------+
| Tom    | Something  |
| Nick   | yay        |
+--------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit 3: Try this for your `$query`

```
insert into table1 select coalesce(email,'".$epost."') as email, coalesce(name,'".$namn."') as name from table1 
where email='".$epost."' on duplicate key update name = values (name);
```

Comment: I have an id for each which is set to auto increment. (Not sure how that makes a difference?) email is set to unique.

Comment: Ideas and users are two separate tables. What I'm trying to do is: Update user name, if there is no username already, if there is a user name in the field name, then don't make any changes

Comment: @Alisso See edit, it really is a simple one. Got totally throw off the scent with the duplicate stuff sorry.

Comment: It's what I'm looking for!!! Only in my case the e-mail is the unique field not the name (and I still haven't made it work, but I'm working on it.)

Comment: @Alisso Yeah, I just threw together a quick one. Just swap the fields around if you need to in your query :)

Comment: I can't make it work, but this is an awesome answer just the same! :)

Comment: @Alisso Is the table you have in the question the full table? I don't expect an Accepted unless it is really solved :)

Comment: updated the image to the full table. id is unique & AI, email is unique, name is just any name

Comment: @Alisso Okay, I am sort of addled right now, but try that. If that doesn't work, I will look at it again in the morning :)

Comment: I entered a copy of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/yXqQq/  still not working :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update a field that is already exist, you can do this as;

```
-- MySQL Reference
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);

-- so your code
INSERT INTO users
         (email, name)
     VALUES
         ('" .$epost. "',  '" .$namn. "')

     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email=VALUES(email), name=VALUES(name)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

**UPDATE**

At this point, you need "MySQL conditional insert". Let's try it;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)

INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES('kerem', 'qeremy[atta]gmail[dotta]com');
INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES('test', 'test@example.com');

>> 2 rows inserted. ( Query took 0.0005 sec )

-- this is your part (regarding email field is UNIQUE, so WHERE email='search email')

INSERT INTO users (name, email)
    SELECT 'test', 'test@example.com' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'test@example.com' LIMIT 1
    );

>> 0 rows inserted. ( Query took 0.0003 sec )
```

https://www.google.com/search?q=conditional+insert+mysql

http://allurcode.com/2011/04/15/mysql-conditional-insert/ (which is useful search result)

**UPDATE 2**

If this does not work for you, then you can do your work like (just an input);

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO users (name, email) VALUES('$name', '$email')");
if (!mysql_insert_id()) {
   mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name' WHERE name='' AND email='$email'");
}

Or;

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name' WHERE name='' AND email='$email'");
if (mysql_affected_rows() < 1) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES('$name', '$email')");
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this: INSERT INTO users
         (email, name)
     VALUES
         ('" .$epost. "',  '" .$namn. "')

     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name)    if name == ''

Comment: `on duplicate` statement works only unique or primary key defined. Which is unique or primary?

Comment: So you need "MySQL conditional insert".

Comment: isn't that what INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  is?

Comment: No, at this point ON DUPLICATE is useless. See the answer, it's updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest this solution using the control function IFNULL(exp1,exp2), defined as "if exp1 is not null, returns exp1; if exp1 is null, returns exp2".

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

```
INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ('$name','$email')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = IFNULL(name, VALUES(name))
```

Of course you must be beyond this somehow, but it helped me.